# suggest multiple app when click on anchor tag

Tags: android, html

I want do simple task. When I open website in mobile and click on this number it should ask for which app you want to use like dial, message or whats app. For single task I know how to do it. How to do it single URL?

```
<a href="tel:+918983160662">8983160662</a>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
<a href="sms:+437722735932">contact</a>
```

Comment: Google keywords: `android intentchooser`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in a single URL. The prompt functionality you see when you click a phone number in some desktop  browsers isn't present on mobile I don't think. Unless you get the user to hold down on the number where native options will kick in asking what they want to do with it, whereby WhatsApp, texting will probably be an option.

To achieve what you want you would need a link, that prompts your own custom made dialogue with JavaScript that acts on a certain url. ie. Whatsapp, Skype etc based on what the user chose.